# Is self hosted Owin faster (.Net Framework 4.5) than asp.net core Api (AspNetCore 1.1.1)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, owin, .net-core

I was doing performance comparison between Self Hosted Web Api using Owin with .Net 4.5 framework and Self Hosted Web Api using aspnet core (Aspnet core 1.1.1 with .Net Core). To my surprise I found Self Hosted Web Api is faster than aspnet core. Is there any thing wrong with server side or client side code which is testing the performance?

For most of the benchmarks on the Web, it is stated that AspNetCore is in general faster than Web Api. However this test is giving me different reults. Please see the following results

**Self Hosted Web Api with Owin** - Time taken - Elapsed miliseconds= 10319.8858

**AspNet core Web Api with Kestrel** - Time taken - Elapsed miliseconds= 11903.8001

Server side code for **Self Hosted Web Api with Owin** and .Net framework 4.5

```
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        StringBuilder bigString = new StringBuilder();
        for (long i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
        {
            bigString.Append("This really big string" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        var someString = "Elapsed time" + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "data " + bigString.ToString();
        return new string[] { someString };
    }
```

Serve side code for **aspnet core web api** (Aspnet core 1.1.1 with .Net Core)

```
 public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw=new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        StringBuilder bigString = new StringBuilder();            
        for (long i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
        {
            bigString.Append("This really big string" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        var someString= "Elapsed time" + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "data " + bigString.ToString();
        return new string[] { someString };
    }
```

Client side logic to test the performance

```
string baseAddress = "http://localhost:5000/";
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        // Start OWIN host 
        //using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
        {
            // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();                            
            watch.Start();
            var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result;
            //Console.WriteLine(response);
           var d= response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //Console.WriteLine();
            watch.Stop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Elapsed miliseconds= " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: It seems you just measure your network speed in this case (and probably also perfomance of building large strings with string builder).

Comment: @Evk Server and client are hosted on the same machine. Please see the url it contains localhost:5000

Answer (score 0):

The "test" in  question is pure non-sense.

#### First wrong assumption: Creating/submitting big data equals performance testing

You are testing how fast your memory is.

When you iterate 6000000 adding a string to a buffer, you effectively test how fast allocation and garbage collection is, because every time your string builder's buffer gets full, it needs to be extended and the old content copied over to the new string builder.

And once you the given garbage collection generation is full, it will need to be collected.

And on top of that, you also call `bigString.ToString()` which basically reads the whole buffer and allocate it in it's own memory again.

Your string is 24 bytes long (22 + new line). You do 6000000 (6 million) iterations. That's a buffer size of 6000000 * 24 * 2 (strings in .NET are internally UTF-16) = 288000000 bytes or 274.658 Mbyte. StringBuilder is initialized with 16 characters (32 bytes) (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Memory)).

This means, in order to grow up to 288000000 bytes, the StringBuilder needs to resize itself **26 times** (Formula 16*(2^(n-1)); for n = 26 this gives 16*(2^25), which results in a buffer of 536870912 bytes (512 MB).

But during the resizing, you allocated a total of 1073741808 bytes (roughly 1 GB) of RAM and GC'd most-likely most of it. Plus another 288000000 bytes when calling `bigString.ToString()`. So you allocated roughly 1.75 GB RAM.

To get that in a picture let WolframAlpha draw that for you: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Total[16*(2^(n-1)),+n%3D1+to+26]

So in all, you measured how fast your memory allocation (1.75 GB allocating), StringBuilder's buffer resize (26 resizes for roughly 750 MB overhead...) and how fast the garbage collection (... which likely to have been gc'd most of the 750-1024 MB overhead, as the GC suspends all threads while garbage collecting) is.

#### Second wrong assumption: Serialization/transmission of big data is a measure of performance

Similar to the first one, you are not testing the framework but the serialization and the connection (as well as allocation on the client).

#### Final Words

If you want to test performance of the framework and the underlying TCP stack (Kestrel/UVLib vs Whatever Owin uses), do it with a small sample. Like `return "Hello world.";` and utilize http pipelining, this is where you gain most performance single request.

When you use controller you also test performance of MVC routing. When using a single middleware (via `app.Use(...)`), you test just Kestrel.

And before making such non-sense tests in future, you'd be very advised to read MSDN on the "[Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)" to better understand why the whole thing you did is non-sense and it only measures memory & GC, but not ASP.NET (Core or Legacy), .NET Core or .NET Framework

Comment: The lengthy explanation given by you talks about different things. But it fails to explain why one test is performing better than the other. Garbage collection, Serialization, memory allocation are the services provided by framework. Any real world application will involve all these things. Simple Hello world test suggested by you is of no use since it does not consider all these things. Objective of test was to consider how API written in Asp.Net Core and Self hosted API will perform under heavy work load.

Comment: Likely a difference in the garbage collection, as .NET Core and .NET Framework are different runtimes and likely have differences in the ways their GC's work. Look at the techempower benchmarks. ASP.NET Core gets up to 1.25 million requests per second where ASP.NET MVC 5 (running on mono though, which is good way slower than .NET Framework) only got 50k requests / second in Round 11. Both on a simple controller/middleware which returns "Hello World". It measures the real overhead of the framework and not of the GC/memory (though memory is bottleneck at some point)

Comment: Garbage collection will come into picture even in case API is simply returning "Hello World". As benchmarks​ suggested asp.net core handles 1.25 million requests/second. With each request memory allocation has to happen for "Hello World' and as soon as request is complete string will be unreferenced. At some point GC has to do clean up since here we are having huge no of requests.

Comment: Also benchmark doesn't compare self hosted web api versus asp.net core web api. I didn't find a comparison like this on the internet. This is the real motivation for this question

Comment: Yes, gc will happen with hello world app, But it will only be very little percentage of the request, because only new generations will be collected.  But in your case gc and allocation will be about 95% of the request time.  This makes your "test" worthless.  The overhead of old ASP.NET is to big.  32kb per request vs. ca. 2kb in ASP.NET Core. At 1 million requests this is GBs of allocations!